# Removing unnecessary edges from an updated cycle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be undirected, and let $s,t∈V$ and $C⊆E$ be a cycle that contains $s$ and $t$. As a dynamic algorithm, during each phase, the given input is a set of edges $F⊆E$ which are to be removed from the cycle. After removing these edges, I want to get rid of redundant edges. By redundant, I mean edges that can now no longer be part of this cycle. For example,

$$ C=\left\{ (s,v_1),(v_1,v_2),(v_2,t),(t,v_3),(v_3,s),(v_1,v_4),(v_4,v_5), (v_5,v_1) \right\}$$

So the cycle's full path is: $s\rightarrow v_1 \rightarrow v_4 \rightarrow v_5 \rightarrow v_1 \rightarrow v_2 \rightarrow t \rightarrow v_3 \rightarrow s$.

If the removed edges are $\left\{ (v_4,v_5) \right\}$ then the cycle path is $s\rightarrow v_1 \rightarrow v_2 \rightarrow t \rightarrow v_3 \rightarrow s$. And then the edges that are no longer necessary are $(v_1,v_4)$ and $(v_5,v_1)$, despite not being removed.

Basically, my question is how to identify these edges.

If the cycle given is simple, then we can simply return an empty set, as there is no longer any smaller cycle.

For a non-simple cycle, I'd like to find the minimal set of unnecessary edges (unnecessary as I showed in the example before, meaning edges that are no longer usable for the cycle), such that the remaining edges are an $s,t$-cycle (the remaining edges must contains $s$ and $t$).

I tried locating subsets of $C$ that have been hit by $F$ and thus cannot be used, but its seems every rule I try to make has a counterexample.

Running an $s,t$-flow algorithm seems a bit unprecise as well, as it might find some sub-cycle which is smaller then the one I want (I want to maximize the cycle out of the remaining edges).

Another way is to look on the cycle as a string that indicates the order in which we move on the cycle. Then, we can try to see in which places the edges were erased. Then, we go left and right until we find the same vertex again. But this can take $O\left( \left| V \right| ^2 \right)$ when described as an algorithm, and I'm looking for something more timewise efficient.

Updates:

- Edges cannot be used twice.
- The order of the vertices in the cycles does not have to remain the same.

Comment: Does your definition of a cycle allow the same edge to be traversed more than once?

Comment: Do we need to keep the order in which the vertices were first visited in the cycle?

Comment: Hey! Clarified,

Comment: Can you detail your $\mathcal{O}(|V|^2)$ algorithm ? Even when $F$ is a single edge, this problem seems not trivial to solve optimally...

Comment: Is it the case that $E$ is irrelevant, because you are only considering edges in $C$?  Are you asking for the largest Eulerian subgraph of $C-F$ that contains $s$ and $t$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G'$ be the graph formed with only the vertices of your cycle (or more precisely circuit as you allow repeated vertices). This graph must be eulerian.
The goal is to find the biggest eulerian subgraph (non-induced) of $G'\setminus F$ (with non-zero degree for $s$ and $t$). If we forget $s$ and $t$, this problem is NP-Hard, as show the reduction I found in a comment of [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/45885/complexity-of-finding-the-largest-induced-subgraph-with-all-even-degrees) :

> The reduction uses the NP-complete problem Hamiltonian cycle in cubic graphs. If in an n-vertex cubic graph each edge is subdivided by a new vertex, then the resulting graph has a ≥2n-vertex Eulerian subgraph if and only if the original graph has a Hamiltonian cycle. Without the connectivity of the Euclidean subgraph, however, the existence of the Hamiltonian cycle is not guaranteed. Therefore, the reduction makes essential use of connectivity - Andras Fargo

I don't have the reference for this reduction.

I don't know if the problem is still NP-complete when $F$ is reduced to a single edge.